# Android Preference Dialog Theme not changing

Tags: android, preference

I am trying to change the theme of a preference dialogs.

My Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Preferences.Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:divider">@color/text_green</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_green</item>
    <item name="android:background">#fff0f0f0</item>
</style>
```

Preference Activity:

```
public class SettingsPrefActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Preferences_Dialog);
```

It is changing the preference objects not the preference dialog objects.

Example: This is from my preference activity. It shouldn't be green

[image: SS from Preference]

This is my dialog. The divider and title should be green.

[image: ss of Pref Dialog]

Answer (score -1):

`setTheme()` must be called before inflating your layout. This normally occurs in `setContentView()`, but in your case for PreferenceActivity, it occurs in `addPreferencesFromResource()`.

In short, change the content of your `onCreate()` to:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Preferences_Dialog);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    ...
}
```

Personally, I prefer keeping this sort of logic more closely coupled with my view (outside of my model, or Activity code) by describing the theme in the manifest. I suggest you take a look at the recommendations for [Applying Themes and Styles to the UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles). For example, by using:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Or:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Preferences">
```

Also bear in mind that the use of PreferenceActivity is now discouraged in favor of PreferenceFragment.